# Random issue with Visual Studio 2008 debugging website against IIS (XP)

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I get a random issue with VS2008 (although not that random several times a day!) where-by I attempt to debug a web application using my local IIS instance, around 5/10 times it starts up the browser and is fine, however sometimes it goes into debug mode (following a long pause) without actually starting the browser, then when I stop debugging the browser kicks in!?

The only way I can resolve this is by restarting IIS, but it's still a pain.

Any ideas why this is happening?  By the way I use firefox to debug but this still happens if I debug through IE.

Thanks
Kev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it is usually better (and faster) to attach to the IIS process and debug that way.

You can then keep your browser open on the page you care about rather than having to navigate back to the page you are testing.

So:

1. Debug > Attach to Process ...
2. Select aspnet_wp.exe (usually the first in the list)
3. press the "Attach" button
4. enjoy